# R - Apply a 3 arguments function to each line of a 3 columns matrix, using as arguments each value of the 3 columns

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a function getSentiment (from the "edgar" R package) that delivers me a dataframe with a set of measures, that works like:

```
getSentiment(cik.no = "cik_number", form.type = "form_type", filing_year = year)
```

That function doesn't work with vectors, so I cannot check multiple cik numbers using C("cik_number1", "cik_number2"), same thing for the form type and filing year.
On my side I have a matrix of 700+ companies with 3 columns, one for the cik numbers, one for the form type, and the last one for the filing year.
What I want is to apply the getSentiment function to each line/observation of the matrix, taking as argument the correspondent value of each line present in the 3 columns.
Then, to finish it, I would like to rbind all the dataframes I got for each company into 1 big matrix, in the order they got executed.

Maybe the solutions is simple, I started to learn R in May, but I cannot get to it.
If anyone can help me it would be great since what I'm working on is for my Master thesis.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is called `data` and the column are in the order `cik.no`, `form.type` and `filing_year` you can try the following.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, apply(data, 1, function(x) 
              getSentiment(cik.no = x[1], form.type =x[2], filing_year = x[3])))
```

And similarly this solution using `Map` should work as well.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, Map(getSentiment, data[[1]], data[[2]], data[[3]]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, also to the others who answered so quickly, the solution using Map was the best one.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a vector with the indices of the rows of your matrix, you can use this as the input to the function `map_dfr` from the `purrr` package. This function applies the provided function to every element of the provided vector (here your row index) and binds together the resulting data.frame.

```r
test_mat <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)

test_fun <- function(a, b, c) {
  data.frame(c1 = a,
             c2 = 2 * b,
             c3 = 3 * c)
}

number_row <- seq_len(nrow(test_mat))

res <- purrr::map_dfr(number_row, ~test_fun(test_mat[.x, 1],
                                            test_mat[.x, 2],
                                            test_mat[.x, 3]))
res
#>   c1 c2 c3
#> 1  1  8 21
#> 2  2 10 24
#> 3  3 12 27
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For your function, change it to:

```r
res <- purrr::map_dfr(number_row, ~getSentiment(cik.no[.x, 1],
                                                form.type[.x, 2],
                                                filing_year[.x, 3]))
```

(Assuming the order of `cik.no`, `form.type` and `filing_year` in your data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pmap` function in the `tidyverse purrr` package. The outputs will be a list of return matrices from your function.  You can then `rbind` the outputs together:

```
library(tidyverse)
paramlist <- list(cik.no, form.type, filing.year) # the parameters are vectors
outputs <- pmap(paramlist, getSentiment)
final <- do.call(rbind, outputs)
```